# URL rewrite (ISAPI)

Tags: url-rewriting, isapi, isapi-rewrite, isapi-redirect

I have a section of a website I'm building that is for the user's account pages.

The map of this bit of the site is like this:

```
*root*/account/details.php
*root*/account/subscriptions.php
*root*/account/options.php
```

I want to make it so that if a user goes to:

```
*root*/account
```

They are redirected to

```
*root*/account/details.php
```

The basic rewrite would be something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^account/ account/details.php [L]
```

However this rule means that all pages (subscriptions,options) also redirect to details which is obviously problematic.

How can I edit my rule so that it only redirects  *root*/account to the details page, and leaves the other pages to work independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to rewrite only /account/, but not /account/XXXX. In this case try: `RewriteRule ^account/$ account/details.php [L]`
In this case '$' identified the end of the pattern, so nothing after /account/ will be looked at.